# How to get video files from team-recording-bot

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Intro: We are creating a bot to record the team meeting. After the meeting gets over
we should get the recordings files in video format.

Issue: We have implemented this code(https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples/teams-recording-bot)
using azure kubernetes. We are able to join the team meeting and recording start automatically and we get audio wav file format in zip file to our local but we need video files.
So how can we get the video files in .zip file to our local.

Implementation of code: We have used ivideosocket. But we dont no how we can implement code to get video
so that we can save that video to our local in .zip file.

```
`
private void OnVideoMediaReceived(object sender, VideoMediaReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.GraphLogger.Info($"[{e.SocketId}]: Received Video: [VideoMediaReceivedEventArgs(Data=<{e.Buffer.Data.ToString()}>, Length={e.Buffer.Length}, Timestamp={e.Buffer.Timestamp}, Width={e.Buffer.VideoFormat.Width}, Height={e.Buffer.VideoFormat.Height}, ColorFormat={e.Buffer.VideoFormat.VideoColorFormat}, FrameRate={e.Buffer.VideoFormat.FrameRate})]");

            // TBD: Compliance Recording bots can record the Video here
            e.Buffer.Dispose();
        }

`
```